# Unable to delete images in Media Library

Tags: images, media, media-library, customization, library

I have tons of images in my site. Now I'm trying to delete the broken images  in the media library but it is not being deleted. Whenever I refresh the page, it is still there.

How can I delete those images?

Comment: Although i am discouraged about answering this question (since you didn't react to the other answer), But still, what do you mean by `Broken`? Is the url to the image broken in media library or what?

Comment: @JackJohansson Sorry. I am still in the middle of doing all the answers you provided in my other question. Regarding this one, yes, the url in the image is broken and some images(not broken URL) are just unnecessary so I will delete it because it is taking a lot of memory.

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean `but it is not being deleted`? What happens after you delete the media from library? Is it removed from media library window or not?